# How can I get the number of occurences from 2 queries to put them in a chart in Access

Tags: sql, ms-access

I am new using access and sql so I might be organising my data wrongly.

I am trying to create some charts based the number of occurrences of documents opened and closed per month.

The data comes  from a query that I have previously created that looks like the following:

[image: query with dates opened and closed]

I have tried 2 options:

- One is making 1 query that counts the number of occurrences, however, since the closure date and opening date are related to the ID I end up with something like the following table. The count for the number of closures are related to the date opened and not the date closed.

[image: Count of number opened and closed per month]

- I have tried making two different queries, one for count opened and one for count closed. But I don't know how to combine them to get a single bar chart in a report. Furthermore, the query for the closed count gives an additional row because not all documents are closed so some records are left empty.

[image: closed count query]

What I'm getting at is, how can I change the queries above to put the data in a bar chart to compare the number of documents opened and closed per month in the past year. I would also like to get the cumulative amount of documents opened and closed by the end of the month.

Comment: Actual table and field names and raw data sample would be nice.

Comment: I would rather see raw data table, not a query from that table. Data should be provided as text table not image so it is easier to bring into db for testing. https://www.tablesgenerator.com/text_tables#. I cannot look at again until tonight.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: What do you mean by 'cumulative' - a count to include all records to date? That should be a simple aggregate query. Edit question to show desired output or start a new question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Working from the query dataset you provided, consider:

Query1:

```
SELECT NCRNo, DateIssued AS TransDate, "Issued" AS TransType FROM DaysOpen
UNION SELECT NCRNo, ClosureDate, "Closed" FROM DaysOpen WHERE NOT ClosureDate IS NULL;
```

Chart RowSource:

```
TRANSFORM Count(*) AS [Count] 
SELECT (Format([TransDate],"MMM 'YY")) 
FROM [Query1]   
GROUP BY (Year([TransDate])*12 + Month([TransDate])-1),(Format([TransDate],"MMM 'YY")) 
PIVOT [TransType];
```

Note that I have Access 2010 so this is using classic MSGraph, not Modern Chart.
[image]

Monthly difference of Issued and Closed:

```
SELECT Format([TransDate],"yyyymm") AS YrMo, Sum(IIf([TransType]="Issued",1,-1)) AS Diff
FROM Query1
GROUP BY Format([TransDate],"yyyymm");
```

Comment: thanks for you reply, but i cannot seem to make this work. the Query1 you've created is giving the correct information however, the report gives a blank chart even after updating the Rowsource. Could you explain to me what the Rowsource code does ?

Comment: Don't understand your confusion. Chart must use data and the query is the data in structure to build bar chart. I let the chart wizard construct the RowSource query. It is a CROSSTAB query.

Comment: Thanks for your help, it works. I am also trying to graph the running total of the issued and closed documents as well as the difference between the number of documents opened and closed in a month. However I am stuck once again: should a create a new crosstab query for each of the running totals ? If so how do I go about it?

Comment: Running sum or count in Access query is not simple. Review https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/troubleshoot/access/create-a-running-totals-query and https://www.msaccesstips.com/2019/11/running-sum-in-ms-access-query.html and http://allenbrowne.com/subquery-01.html#YTD